# How can I modify the title of the MDTopAppBar when a button, located in a separate class, is clicked?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I modify the title of the MDTopAppBar in response to a user selecting a button within the NavigationDrawer, such as updating the title to match the selected button's label (e.g. "Coffee")?

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView

class MainLayout(Screen):
    pass
    
class NavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):    
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
    
class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        kivy_layout = Builder.load_file("layout.kv")
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().run()
```

layout.kv

```
<NavigationDrawer>

    MDNavigationDrawerMenu:
        
        MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
            title: "MyApp"
            text: "Bottom Text"
            source: "icon64.png"
            spacing: "10dp"
                
        MDNavigationDrawerDivider:
            
        MDNavigationDrawerItem:
            text: "Coffee"
            icon: "coffee"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"

        MDNavigationDrawerItem:
            text: "History"
            icon: "history"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"
            
        MDNavigationDrawerItem:
            text: "Settings"
            icon: "cog"
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 3"

        MDNavigationDrawerDivider:

<MainLayout>
    MDScreen:

        MDTopAppBar:    
            id: top
            title: "Title"
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            elevation: 4
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

        MDNavigationLayout:

            MDScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager

                MDScreen:
                    name: "scr 1"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Coffee"
                        halign: "center"   

                MDScreen:
                    name: "scr 2"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "History"
                        halign: "center"
                
                MDScreen:
                    name: "scr 3"

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Settings"
                        halign: "center"

            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)

                NavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

After attempting to resolve the issue on my own through various means, including attempting to create a solution and conducting research online for potential solutions, I was unable to find a satisfactory resolution. As a result, I have determined it necessary to seek assistance through this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an id to the MDNavigationDrawerHeader so you can access it from the class.

```
MDNavigationDrawerHeader:
    id: drawer_header
    title: "MyApp"
    text: "Bottom Text"
    source: "icon64.png"
    spacing: "10dp"
```

Then you need to add a method to the NaviagtionDrawer class to make the update. You will access your NavDrawer Title by calling self.ids.drawer_header.title

```
class NavigationDrawer(MDScrollView):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()

    def set_title(self, title):
        self.ids.drawer_header.title = title
```

Finally, you need to tell each button to call the set_title method that I created to actually do the update.

```
MDNavigationDrawerItem:
    text: "Coffee"
        icon: "coffee"
        on_press:
            root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
            root.set_title(self.text)
            root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"
```

To change the MDTopAppBar title add the following line to each of the on_press events:

```
app.change_title(self.text) # call method in main app

ie.
on_press:
    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
    root.set_title(self.text)
    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"
    app.change_title(self.text) # call method in main app
```

Then add the following method to your main app.

```
    def change_title(self, title):
        self.root.ids.top.title = title
ie.
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        Builder.load_file("layout.kv")
        return MainLayout()

    def change_title(self, title):
        self.root.ids.top.title = title
```

Comment: I see, but I am supposed to change the title of MDTopAppBar which is in the other class, how would I do this?

Comment: I just updated my answer to change the MDTopBar title

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it fixed your issue.